Couldn't load qgis.user. Python support will be disabled. Windows 10
Qgis crashed when I was using python console inside QGIS and appear this mensage bellow:

Couldn't load qgis.user.
Python support will be disabled.
traceback.print_exception() failed
Python version:
QGIS version:
3.22.5-Białowieża 'Białowieża', c2723178
Python path:

how to solve?

I suggest you uninstall the old QGIS and install it again using OSGeo4W Installer.
